# Why does the query optimizer fail when I put an or statement before an in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a relatively simple query that gets all history entries from an object and all related objects. When I want to add an additional ObjectID to the search results the performance is dramatically different depending on whether I use OR or UNION and I don't understand why the optimizer cannot simply optimize the OR version of the query.

Here is what I do

```
SELECT *
FROM ObjectMain 
INNER JOIN ObjectHistory ON ObjectMain.ObjectID = ObjectHistory.ObjectID
WHERE ObjectMain.ObjectID IN 
(
 SELECT ObjectID FROM RelatedObjects WHERE RelationID = 
  (SELECT RelationID FROM RelatedObjects  WHERE ObjectID = 123)
)
```

If I now want to add ObjectID = 999 to the results I can do this two ways

```
WHERE ObjectMain.ObjectID = 999 OR ObjectMain.ObjectID IN ...
```

Or

```
 (SELECT RelationID FROM RelatedObjects  WHERE ObjectID = 123) UNION ALL (SELECT 999)
```

The first version performs abysmal while the second performs normally. Difference is orders of magnitude. Since this kind of scenario can occur often I'd really like to understand what is going on here.

EXECUTION PLANS:
[Exec Plan OR](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyGaVRB3Y)
[Exec Plan UNION](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bk_eU0H2t)

I added the execution plans. I can clearly see that they are different, but I don't really understand them. SQL is not my primary expertise and my experience with execution plans is limited at best. Mostly I don't understand in practical terms how such a simple query can have such disastruous performance simple because I'm using an OR statement. It is 6448 miliseconds for 664 rows returned vs 60.

Comment: would `where objectmain.objectid in (123,999)` do it?  Not sure i get what you mean though.

Comment: Can you include the query plans for the 2 differently performing queries via Paste the Plan please?

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Use table aliases and qualify column names in the subqueries, so we can understand which columns belong to which table.

Comment: Maybe similar scenario to here? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea49ac48a7f59e5a1cfb873cc744225b - the `OR` does end up implemented with a `UNION ALL`  (concatenation operator) but the plan is different from the manual `UNION ALL`

Comment: I've just added the execution plans